# Dependency details for module shows the same dependency multiple times

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project with a "base" module, a library module called "ViewLib" and an "installed" module. I have put the following in `build.gradle` inside "installed":

```
implementation project(":ViewLib")
implementation project(":base")
```

The dependency graph looks like this (there are three arrows to the same dependency)

[image: Dependency graph]

**Why is this?**

and

**Does it matter?**

---

**Some extra info** that could help:

If I choose devRelease instead of devDebug, it shows the same dependency twice instead.

The only difference between the release and debug buildtypes are that I've included one extra proguard file in debug.

Comment: Hey did you find the answer. Also, how did you get that screen in the above screen shot?

Comment: Still haven't found the answer. However it turned out that the errors I'm getting is caused by Proguard files not configured properly. I have changed the question to reflect this.
The screen shot is from the (i) mark in the Build Variants tab in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching the same issue through many pages and I didn't found nothing. But I downloaded the Android Studio 3.5 Beta 3 and I started to test this scenario and it didn't happened. I think, it was an issue in the current Android Studio. So in the next release the Android studio team  will fix it.

[Android Studio Version 3.5 Beta 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaUMf.png)

[Modular Android Application - Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPFR1.png)

As you can see in those images it seems this issue doesn't appear. :)